# How to use Criteria.ne in a group operation using spring data mongodb aggregation framework?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use spring data mongodb's Criteria.ne operation in a Group Operation but haven't got it right so far. This portion lacks an example in spring data documentation. Can anyone provide me with an example on how I can do it? This is how I am trying to do it:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria = criteria.ne(new String[] {"$someKey", "$someotherkey"});
Field field = Fields.field("comparison", criteria.toString());
fields = fields.and(field);
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group(fields);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using Spring Data MongoDB 1.3.2.SNAPSHOT

Comment: Filed a ticket with spring data about the same: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-784 Do upvote it if you are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using group you can use this sintax  with a mongoTemplate.

```
mongoTemplate.group(Criteria.where("comparison").ne("value"), "collectionName", GroupBy.key("key1","key2").initialDocument("{}").reduceFunction(" function(obj, prev) {}"), AnyClass.class);
```

that is the same for :

```
db.consorcio_consorcio.group({
    "key": {
        "key1": true,
        "key2": true
    },
    "initial": {},
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {},
    "cond": {
        "comparison": "value"
    }
});
```

Addionality you can use  this webpage for translate query , i think that is helpfully http://www.querymongo.com/